# Regarding Openssl.config file: What is the importance of policy matching when creating a self-signed certificate with the aid of this file?

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, certificate-authority, digital-signature

When trying to go through some material for self-signing a certificate, one of the steps required me to set policy conditions in this config file. See: https://www.phildev.net/ssl/opensslconf.html

The idea is that when you select `policy_match=match`, certain fields in the CA's certificate "must match with the corresponding fields in the client certificate to be signed". Why would a CA's certificate have to have matching fields with a client's certificate?

It all doesn't make sense to me since the client could be an arbitrary entity that has nothing in common with the CA. Can someone explain the scenario in which these would have to match?

Comment: Crossdupe http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37819/meaning-of-policy-matches-when-signing-ssl-certificates Also certs issued by `openssl ca` are **NOT selfsigned**; selfsigned does mean signed under control of the same person, it means signed with the same key as is in the cert.

Comment: I had originally posted this on the crypto site, but all commenters assured me that it was the wrong place. Thats why came here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an arbitrary, administrative decision for the creator of CA what client certificates they want to enable to be signed by the CA.

The `policy_match` in the following configuration line:

```
policy          = policy_match
```

is a chosen name that corresponds to a particular section in the configuration file. That section defines in details each of the

```
[ policy_match ]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
localityName            = supplied
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional
```

Each of the DN fields for the client certificate can be assigned to have the same value as the CA (`match`), be required to be specified (`supplied`), or be optional (`optional`).

The same guide suggests another policy that matches your criteria of "*the client could be an arbitrary entity that has nothing in common with the CA*":

```
[ policy_anything ]
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional
```

Yet if you wanted to create a CA for your organisation, that would allow issuing only certificates for that part of your organisation you can freely set for example:

```
policy          = policy_branch_1

[ policy_branch_1 ]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
localityName            = match
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = supplied
```

Which would required the issued certificates to have first three DN fields matching the CA's certificate.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your answer. Are you saying that a MATCH value for a policy field stipulates that when a CA certificate is used to either create a Certificate Signing Request ("CSR") or sign an existing CSR, that the value of the CA certificate's Subject Name Relative Distinguished Name ("RDN") fields that are specified in the policy with a MATCH value must MUST appear IDENTICALLY as the corresponding Subject Name RDNs in the CSR that is created or signed by the CA certificate?

Comment: @Bill: a CSR is never created with any certificate. People describe issuing a cert as 'signing the CSR' but this is wrong; look at a CSR and the resulting cert and you can see they are different, although partly related. Yes, a policy setting of 'match' requires a particular field in the (Subject) name in CSR (or `-subj` if used), and thus the new cert, to match the field in the CA cert/name -- but it does not check order: the RDNs in the CSR can be in any order but the cert uses the order of the policy settings, unless you use `-preserveDN` as stated on the man page.

Comment: Thanks for answering my comment, Dave.  Now that I have re-read my comment I should have written the words "when a CA certificate is used to either create a Certificate Signing Request ("CSR") or sign an existing CSR" as "when the ca command is used ..."  Most importantly, thanks for confirming that my understanding about the MATCH value for policy RDNs is correct.  That's the critical piece of information I was trying to confirm.