# X.509 - How Is Certificate Chain of Trust "Subject Name"-"Issuer Name" Match Comparison Made?

Tags: certificates, x.509

I keep reading that in an X.509 certificate chain of trust that the "Issuer Name" in a certificate that has been signed by the Issuer must *"match"* the "Subject Name" of the Issuer's certificate.  Exactly how is this match determined?  Do all of the RDNs (Relative Distinguished Names) have to match between both the Subject Name and Issuer Name or is the match determined solely by the RDNs that are present in the Issuer certificate's Subject Name, or is some other match algorithm at work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [x.509 certificate-chain signatures verification](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/186068/x-509-certificate-chain-signatures-verification)

Comment: No.  What I'm trying to understand is the match detail underneath the "Issuer's (CA) name" to "Owner's (CA's) name" in the link you provided.  It's the term "name" that needs more detail.  Speaking precisely (which is sorely lacking when dealing with X.509 stuff), every certificate has a Subject Name and an Issuer Name.  Each of these Names is composed of multiple Relative Distinguished Name ("RDN") fields (e.g., commonName, organizationName, etc.).  My question is what constitutes a "match" between an issuing certificate's Subject Name and its signed certificate's Issuer Name?

Answer (score 1):

As per [RFC 5280 §4.1.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4) (and as specified in [§7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-7.1)), binding is done by using case-insensitive match between `Issuer` distinguished name string of leaf certificate and `Subject` distinguished name string of a potential issuer.

Bear in mind that Key Match, Exact Match, Name Match techniques are used only to bind certificates and build as much chains as possible (build complete chain tree). It doesn't tell anything about trust/validity. When completed, tree is passed to validation routine which excludes invalid/non-suitable certificates and returns only single best chain. Full validation process is defined in [RFC 5280 §6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6).

Certificate validation is a 3-step process:

1. Tree building (from leaf to root)
2. Tree validation (from root to leaf)
3. Revocation checking (from leaf to root)

Name Match binding is used only during first process.

Comment: I understand all of this.  What I don't understand is what constitutes a "match" between an issuing certificate's Subject Name and its signed certificate's Issuer Name.  Is the match made on a specific Relative Distinguished Name field (or fields) that are present in both the Subject Name and the Issuer Name or is some other match mechanism at work?  I'm trying to understand this so that I can configure the policy settings in my OpenSSL config.cnf file correctly.

Comment: I've added all necessary references that describe how name match is performed.

Comment: I've just finished re-reading RFC 5280, Section 6.  I have no clue how that answers my question, but I understand that there are processes much bigger at work than just matching Subject Name and Issuer Name.  Can you give me the "dummies" answer to my question re: "Name Matching," or point me to a "dummies" reference that will explain it to me in layman's terms?

Comment: Read §7.1 of referenced RFC. The link in my answer.

Comment: Is this the answer? "Two distinguished names DN1 and DN2 match if they have the same number of RDNs, for each RDN in DN1 there is a matching RDN in DN2, and the matching RDNs appear in the same order in both DNs.  A distinguished name DN1 is within the subtree defined by the distinguished name DN2 if DN1 contains at least as many RDNs as DN2, and DN1 and DN2 are a match when trailing RDNs in DN1 are ignored."

Comment: The policy settings in openssl config for 'ca' have no effect on chaining, only on whether certain certificates are issued in the first place. If OpenSSL issues the cert at all, the child Issuer is always an exact copy of the parent Subject. And when OpenSSL verifies a chain it simply compares the DER encodings -- which by definition of DER does a consistent ordering of any nonsingleton AVA sets, though practically nobody uses them anyway. Remember SSLeay started long before rfc5280 or even rfc3280.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for enlightening me about the role of the 'ca' policy section in the OpenSSL config.cnf file!  I COMPLETELY misunderstood the language of the OpenSSL "POLICY FORMAT" section of the manual page for the 'ca' command.  Based upon the explanation in this post https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130476/regarding-openssl-config-file-what-is-the-importance-of-policy-matching-when-cr is the policy section's function to stipulate which Subject Name DN fields of the CA certificate will be created identically in the child certificate's Subject Name?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, would you please respond to the question at the end of my last comment?  Thanks for your help - I REALLY appreciate it.

Comment: @Bill: as correctly explained on that other Q, openssl ca 'policy' can _either_ require that a field _match_ the CA, or only require that it be _supplied_ (with any value, not necessarily matching). This is also what the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ca.html#POLICY-FORMAT) says as long as you understand 'certificate DN' to mean '(newly issued) certificate (Subject) DN'

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085, for confirming my understanding with "as long as you understand 'certificate DN' to mean '(newly issued) certificate (Subject) DN'".  That's what was confusing me!